# RxJava (Android) - Is there any harm in keeping a Scheduler alive?

Tags: android, singleton, rx-java, scheduler, rx-java2

I have a singleton that holds a reference to my database object. What I would like to do is constraint any database operation to a single IO thread.

First I tried with the following:

```
class SQLSingleton{

 ...

 public Observable<MyObject> query(final String id){

   return Observable.fromCallable(() -> {

       //database operations here
   })
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
 }

 ...
}
```

The problem with this approach is that Schedulers.io() might give a different thread from its pool for each subscriber that subscribes to my observable above (and I don't want that, I want the code to be executed on the the same thread at all times).

I then moved to the approach of holding a Scheduler myself:

```
class SQLSingleton{

 private final Scheduler schedulerIODatabase;

 public SQLSingleton(){
      schedulerIODatabase = Schedulers.newThread();
 }

 public Observable<MyObject> query(final String id){

   return Observable.fromCallable(() -> {

       //database operations here
   })
   .subscribeOn(schedulerIODatabase)
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
 }

 ...
}
```

Since I am new to RxJava (and it looks like it has a lot of pitfalls), I ask: **Is there any harm in keeping that Scheduler object alive** (keep in mind that SQLSingleton is a singleton, therefore that Scheduler will also be)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
schedulerIODatabase = Schedulers.newThread();
```

This has no effect because `newThread` hands out a fresh thread every time it is applied with `subscribeOn`, similar to `io()` but without thread reuse.

You can't pin and reuse a particular RxJava thread in RxJava 1.x but you can do it in RxJava 2 with its extension library component: [SharedScheduler](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#sharedscheduler).

In RxJava 1, you have to provide your own single-threaded `ExecutorService` to `Schedulers.from` which then will use that single `Executor` for all worker invocations. Note that you have to manually manage your `ExecutorService`'s lifecycle and shut it down when your app has to terminate:

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadedExecutor();

Scheduler singleScheduler = Schedulers.from(exec);

Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
   //database operations here
})
.subscribeOn(singleScheduler)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

// ...

exec.shutdown();
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer @akarnokd. Could you please clarify how exactly would I "manually manage your ExecutorService's lifecycle and shut it down when your app has to terminate"? Should I do that on the onDestroy method of my application object? I was under the impression I did not have to care about that as those objects are singletons and therefore will be properly "collected" if the app shuts down.

Comment: I don't know if Android shuts down ExecutorServices automatically or not, it certainly doesn't happen in desktop Java applications. onCreate/onDestroy pair sounds reasonable.